# Why not constructor of super class invoked when we declare the object of sub class?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, constructor

I am a Java programmer, beginner in Python programming. I have noticed unexpected behavior in python programming. I was expecting the print sequence as `B class ,A Class` constructors. But it's executing constructor of A only.

Output as  "Its Constructor of A",Could you please help me to understand flow of execution.  Thanks in advance

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Its constructor of B'    

class A(B):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Its constructor of A'
        #B.__init__(self)

if __name__=='__main__':
    obj=A()
```

Comment: That's just the way Python works. IIRC, even in Java, if you're extending a class whose constructor takes parameters, you have to explicitly call `super(<params>)`. The only difference is that for a superclass which doesn't take params, calling `super()` is optional in Java, whereas in Python you have to call it explicitly.

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

Comment: See also [Understanding Python super() and init methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python you should call the parent's initializer (that's how the `__init__` method is actually called, - "constructor" is something else) explicitly.

You can do it like you did in the commented out line. Better yet, you should use the `super` function, that figures out, which parent to access for you. It only works with [new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/node33.html) though (basically, that means, that the root of your class hierarchy must inherit from `object`).

Comment: What's the difference between a constructor and initializer? Seems to be rather identical to me. Answered my own question: init is called a constructor expression in the python data model: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization

Comment: @Voo: I am sorry, but your statement regarding constructor expression is incorrect. The constructor expression is the "call to the class" as per http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization. ``__init__`` is different from the "constructor" you might be used to from c++ and java, because it does not construct anything: the instance of the class is already present at the time it is called.

Comment: @Voo: The sentence you misinterpreted merely states that `__init__` receives the same arguments that `__new__` received.

Comment: @chepner It says `As a special constraint on constructors, no value may be returned` in that paragraph. That certainly does *not* refer to `__new__` since `__new__` is just fine (in fact rather necessary) with returning an object..

Comment: @Voo Touché. That documentation should be updated. It is possibly left over from the days before `__new__` became available to override. (The following statement needs to be fact-checked:) Although `__init__` has always been simply an initializer, in version 1.x, there was no explicit constructor at the Python level, so one could be loose in describing how `__init__` worked.

Comment: @chepner Well compare `Foo.__init__` to `Foo()`. You may say that `__init__` does not actually allocate memory and that that's __new__'s job which distinguishes it from the c++ version. But neither does the constructor in c++ allocate the memory, it just gets handed the address of an uninitialized chunk of memory. C++ just doesn't give us an option to change the allocation behavior.